# How to use vtk's tcl wrapper on win7?

Tags: cmake, tcl, wrapper, vtk

I have downloaded and built the vtk libraries (with tcl wrapper) with cmake (and have checked vtk_bin to see that they were there. I'm having a hard time finding out how to actually use a tcl script that requires vtk, I receive error messages for vtk functions when I run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was calling it wrong, the scripts can be called vtk blah.tcl, and I made sure the RelWithDebInfo directory was targeted/full